# libz3java in java.library.path,but still reporting no libz3java in java.library.path

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, z3

I created a *scala* project in the *Linux IDEA* integrated environment, which requires the use of *z3solver*.
I tried compiling and installing *Z3soler* using *source code*, and also tried installing the *release version* to make sure z3solver was correctly installed.

However, when loading `libz3java.so`, the error `Exception in thread' main 'java. lang. UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libz3java in java. library. path` occured.

Firstly, I confirmed LD_LIBRARY_PATH. `libz3java` was in the path`/home/xiangmin/z3/build`

```
(base) xiangmin@xiangmin-HP-ZHAN-66-Pro-14-G2:~/cgra/pillarsv2/pillars$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
:/opt/gurobi1000/linux64//lib:/home/xiangmin/z3/build
```

but it didn't work.

Then I copied libz3java to the `/usr/lib` directory, using the command

`ln -s /path/to/libz3java /usr/lib` and `sudo ldconfig` ,but the error still existed.

Also,I tried `System.load("libz3java")` ,and the IDE suggested `can't load library`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/libz3java
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1823)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:782)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1098)
    at tetriski.pillars.mapping.Mapping$.main(Mapping.scala:39)
    at tetriski.pillars.mapping.Mapping.main(Mapping.scala)
```

Here is the output of `java -XshowSettings:properties  -version 2>&1 | grep  library`

```
    java.library.path = 
    sun.boot.library.path = /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/amd64
```

But without `|grep library`,the output contains:

```
 java.library.path = 
        /opt/gurobi1000/linux64//lib
        /home/xiangmin/z3/build
        /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
        /usr/lib64
        /lib64
        /lib
        /usr/lib
```

Thanks a lot for your attention!

Comment: Please show output of `java -XshowSettings:properties  -version 2>&1 | grep  library`

Comment: `java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib -jar your.jar` should work as a command with your symlinks. If you're running in the IDE, make sure the same system property is set for the JVM

Comment: @ggggxm is this resolved. Please help with solution. I'm facing exactly same issue on mac